# How do I split polygons into line segments?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, spatialite

How can I split my polygon file into "segements"? The lines should be broken up like this picture shows:

[image: Spain and Portugal]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Grass, `v.type.bl` can be used to convert polygons to lines. You can follow it up by `v.split` to convert to line segments. The screens are from Qgis. Set max number of vertices to 2 in v.split as shown below.

[image]

**Edit**: The above method will not give you duplicates at d and f. If duplicate segments are required, you could probably replace the first step(v.type.bl) with the Qgis Polygons to Lines tool(Vector -> Geometry tools -> Polygons to Lines).

**Edit#2** - "Any number of Points in a segment" seems a little confusing. You can specify the maximun segment length, or maximum number of vertices to refine your needs in `v.split`. But my gut feeling says that you only need `v.type.bl`. See the output of only v.type.bl below. It gives 6 segments for the three counties from California.

**Edit#3** In GRASS / only the tool v.to.lines is needed to do the job!
[image]

Comment: @Kurt - could you run v.type.bl on your county borders and check the results?

Comment: I importet my map of european countries in grass and run v.type.bl, but it does not work for me. It simply "converts" the polygons to lines, but doesnt generate the segments I need. eg. austria is now *one* line

Comment: @Kurt - did you try v.type.bl followed by v.split? I think we have some understanding problem in defining what a segment is :)     .. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment

Comment: tied it one more time , works now wel. thx for your kind support !!

Comment: @Kurt - glad to know it worked :)

Comment: Why in my Grass GIS on QGIS is don't have a v.type.bl and v.split, please show me how to add on my GRASS GIS

Comment: Can you show me how to processsing v.type.bl  -> v.split on QGIS 3.10. because when i'm trying my result is failed

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to turn your polygons into individual line segments, and that your concern is that segments d & f will not be created as separate lines?

1. You'll use the built-in `Vector | Geometry tools | Polygons to lines` to split the polygons into two separate polylines, creating a new feature;
2. Then you'll need the plugin 'Split Feature' to split the lines into individual segments - after install, select `Plugins | Split Feature` and select the feature created in step 1.

After running that procedure on two simple polygons, just as you show in your example, I ended up with 8 features, two of which are overlapping lines (corresponding to d & f); in the screenshot below, the 'id' refers to the original polygons, and each row is a separate line segment..

[image]

Comment: your approach does the same in qgis what does the procedure vinayan suggested for grass. I end up with *lots* of segements with only 2 points. I will update my post with an picture to clarify