# Split a polygon layer with a line layer?

Tags: qgis

I am drawing administrative regions that have boundaries follow streets in another layer. As these streets are pretty long with many vertices, I don't want to re-trace them. I am looking for a way to "split" the polygon like "split features" tool (the one with the scissors icon).

Before: one whole polygon with a line running through it

[image]

After: the line works as a pair of scissors and split the polygon into 2 parts (in the picture below, the polygons were moved apart for illustrating purpose only)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you have to union both shapes

[image]

Then activate the Polygonizerplugin to reshape the lines to polygones:

[image]

Comment: My Ubuntu Qgis complained about missing shapely.ops when I tried to install Polygonizer plugin. Right now I don't know how to fix it. I'll have to resolve this problem before trying your solution. Thanks.

Comment: It works. What took me so long to accept your answer is that I didn't know how to install shapely.ops. It turns out very easy: go to Ubuntu software center, search for "shapely" and install the only one python-shapely package. After that I was able to install polygonizer plugin and tried out your solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't install the Polygonizer plugin.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem with the Processing Toolbox, using the SAGA `Polygon-line intersection` algorithm.

The process might fail (i.e. no split) if the line end is snapped to a vertex point of the polygon. Extending the line a bit into the neighbouring polygon or outside area sanitizes those pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

[This similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31965/is-there-an-automated-geoprocesing-tool-in-arcgis-to-slice-clip-or-cut-polygon) is for ArcGIS, but may provide you with some ideas from the discussion that you can implement in QGIS.

I also created an ArcGIS model that you may be able to replicate using similar concepts in QGIS.  I tried to describe the concepts that I used [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cd6b2d45df654245b7806a896670a431).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but right now ArcGIS or programming skill is out of my ability.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, the the GRASS command v.type.bl can be used to convert polygons to lines. see the following post: [How do I split polygons into line segments?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32192/how-do-i-split-polygons-into-line-segments)

Comment: I added pictures to clarify the question - thanks a lot.

Comment: @Cao Minh Tu: thanks, the pictures make it clear, I did misunderstand you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the [ArcInfo license](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000037000000.htm), you can use the command "***geom.splitpolysbylines***" in the [Geospatial Modelling Environment](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gmedownload.htm).
It work perfectly.
Make sure, however, that you have ArcGIS 10.1 or ArcGIS 10.0 SP4 and installed ["R" 2.12](http://www.r-project.org/) or higher.

Comment: My question was for Qgis (showed in the tag) - I updated the header to make it more visible. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry about that. Anyhow, if "someone else" has the same type of question, he/she use the option that I suggested above.