# How do you split a feature using an existing line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, topology

Is there a way to split a feature (polygon) using an existing line (selected polyline) in QGIS?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37060/4119. You specified that you want to use a **selected** polyline, but if that response answers your question please let us know.