# GRASS v.overlay.or Error when trying to split a polygon with a line

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, overlay

I am using the Grass plugin in QGIS for Windows (1.8.0).  I am trying to split a polygon with a line feature. I am using the v.overlay.or function within the QGIS Grass plugin.  I have the line layer as input vector map A, and the polygon as input vector B.  When I run the function I get the following error:

```
 v.overlay ainput=cutlines@CompTest atype=line alayer=1 binput=buildings@CompTest btype=area blayer=1 output=bldg_overlay operator=or

 ￼Operator 'or' is not supported for type line
 Finished with error
```

Comment: related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36934/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-polygon-layer-with-a-line-layer

Comment: That is not related to the error I am getting.  I have seen that post a while ago

Comment: true, not related to the error but related to the problem you want to solve and might help others stumbling over this question.

Comment: From [`v.overlay`'s manual](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.overlay.html): _or: also known as 'union' in GIS (only for atype=area)_. Not possible to use **or** with _atype=area_.