# How can I split my polygon file into topological boundaries?

Tags: qgis, topology

This question was asked 8 years ago, but the algorithm in the accepted answer is gone. ([How do I split polygons into line segments?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32192/how-do-i-split-polygons-into-line-segments))

So how can I split my polygon file into "segements"? The lines should be broken up like this picture shows:

[image]

Comment: Which software are you working with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am working with QGIS. I know I can achieve this with https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference#-lines , but nodejs is not always an option.

Comment: `Polygons to lines`, then `dissolve`, then `multi-part to single-part`, all tools are part of the vector toolbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have installed QGIS Desktop with Grass, you can use the the processing "v.to.lines"

[image]

Result:
[image]